# find the general solution of the differential equation with $e^x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac {dy}{dx} = (e^x - e^{-x})^2 $$

I am not sure how to find the general solution of this given problem. It is the e^x that is throwing me off .. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)^2$$?

Comment: This is just about finding an anti-derivative. Apply binomial theorem and integrate.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Note that $y$ is the antiderivative (indefinite integral) of the right hand side. Can you do that integration?

Comment: However, changing the variable on the right to $y'=(e^y-e^{-y})^2$ could be more interesting. It transforms to $u'=2(u-1)^2$ under $u=e^{2y}$.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate directly
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = (e^x - e^{-x})^2$$
$$y(x) =  \int (e^x - e^{-x})^2dx$$
$$y(x) =  \int (e^{2x} - 2+e^{-2x})dx$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$2\sinh x = e^x - e^{-x}$$

and$$ 2\sinh^2x=\cosh(2x)-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Expanding gives $$e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}$$ this is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a separable differential equation:

\begin{align}
&\frac{dy}{dx}=(e^{x}-e^{-x})^{2}\\
&\Rightarrow dy=(e^{x}-e^{-x})(e^{x}-e^{-x})~dx\\
&\Rightarrow \int dy=\int (e^{2x}+e^{-2x}-2)~dx\\
&\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}-2x+C.
\end{align}

As mentioned in other answers, you could also use the hyperbolic sine function.

Answer (score 0):

RHS equals $ 4 \sinh^2 x $

Solution is $ y(x) = \int 4 \sinh^2 x dx = -2x + \sinh (2x) + c $